# libxml parse html - Unpaired Tags broke

Tags: c++, libxml2

I need parse html page in c++ with libxml. I face a problem, when using some    function doc = htmlParseDoc( (xmlChar*)ptr, NULL ); console notice a problem seems like parser broke on
li>Now li - unpaired tag. Parser say number open tag li mismatch closed tags /li. Maybe some help what to do with this ?
I presure for eny help and sorry for engish it's not my native language. I was try tidy but tidy trankate this part of html with message. I was try to parse with xpath interface but this not worked.

Comment: Check out this question for how to parse HTML with libxml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800104/html-parsing-with-libxml

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using managed code (C#) on Windows, you could use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to work with this erroneous HTML input.

Otherwise, something like [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) might work for you.